# Can I use one Log4Net config file for multiple (related) solutions?

Tags: configuration, log4net, log4net-configuration

I have executable projects A and B in solutions sA and sB. Both of these solutions reference projects C, D, etc... as they are similar in functionality and so share a lot of common code.

I've happily implemented Log4Net into sA by keeping the dll and config file in a parent folder of the two solutions and referencing them from sA. The config file was added to project A so that during the build it is copied into the `bin\Debug` or `Release` folder and available during run-time.

My problem is this - since C, D, etc are common projects, they are referencing the original golden source file and not any project-specific config. However, when I added the config file to A, it was copied into the project folder, so I am no longer editing the original. If I add the file to B then I now have three files, which will undoubtedly fall out of sync.

Is there a way I can have the projects reference the original and copy that into the appropriate `bin` folder, effectively having one config file across sA and sB? Is there another solution I'm overlooking?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you look for [Add an existing file to a project as link](http://visualstudiohacks.com/options/add-an-existing-file-to-a-project-without-copying-it/)?

[image]

Hope this helps

Comment: This is perfect - I'd completely forgotten about that feature! This way I can maintain a single source but edit it transparently from each solution. Thanks.